# Convert Javascript Date to YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS+00:00 (with timezone offset)

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

I would like to convert a Javascript Date (as in `const currentDate = new Date();`) to the format below:

`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS+00:00` (I know the timezone will depend on the timezone I am).

But I need the timezone in this format: `+HH:00` or `-HH:00`. I guess the minutes for a timezone will always be zero (but maybe there are some half timezones somewhere).

Anyway, the snippet below for the current date gives me this result:

`2019-11-20T18:02:57.568Z`

Is there an automated way to do that conversion? Or maybe an npm package.

```js
const currentDate = new Date();
console.log(currentDate.toISOString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a NPM package which may do what you want to do in terms of converting these date-times. the link is attached below to the packages NPM page.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-and-time

I believe you can use the date.compile() function for your specified results.